# Using Stanford Core NLP in PHP?

Tags: php, nlp, stanford-nlp, php-java-bridge, java-interop

In Ruby, there is this [this](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp) nice Stanford Core NLP integration gem which simply acts as a bridge to the JVM version. In Python, there is [this](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) one, which while slightly more complicated, appears to do basically the same thing.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a past project, we tried searching for a PHP library that would work well with Core NLP to no avail. We ended up writing our own wrapper by creating methods that would just run an exec command and get us some of the base functionality we needed.